# How to prevent Facet Terms from tokenizing

Tags: tokenize, elasticsearch

I am using Facet Terms to get all the unique values and their count for a field. And I am getting wrong results.

```
term: web 
Count: 1191979 
term: misc 
Count: 1191979 
term: passwd 
Count: 1191979 
term: etc 
Count: 1191979
```

While the actual result should be:

```
term: WEB-MISC /etc/passwd 
Count: 1191979
```

Here is my sample query:

```
{
  "facets": {
    "terms1": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "message"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you update the question with a _short_ example of the data and a _short_ example of the query you're doing, so it's more informative for users coming here from Google searches etc?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If reindexing is an option, it would be the best to change mapping and mark this fields as not_analyzed

```
"your_field" : { "type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" }
```

You can use [multi field type](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/multi-field-type.html) if keeping an analyzed version of the field is desired:

```
"your_field" : {
  "type" : "multi_field",
    "fields" : {
      "your_field" : {"type" : "string", "index" : "analyzed"},
      "untouched" : {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"}
  }
}
```

This way, you can continue using `your_field` in the queries, while running facet searches using `your_field.untouched`.

Alternatively, if this field is stored, you can use a script field facet instead:

```
"facets" : {
  "term" : {
    "terms" : {
      "script_field" : "_fields.your_field.value"
    }
  }
}
```

As the last resort, if this field is not stored, but record source is stored in the index, you can try this:

```
"facets" : {
  "term" : {
    "terms" : {
      "script_field" : "_source.your_field"
    }
  }
}
```

The first solution is the most efficient. The last solution is the least efficient and may take a lot of time on a large index.

Comment: I tried the script_field but it seemed to produce an error.  My current query looks like this though: http://www.pastebin.com/XwJMM7Eq

Comment: It, probably, gives you "unresolved property of identifier: logsource" error. That's because elasticsearch script doesn't know what 'logsource' means. Try replacing it with _fields.logsource

Comment: Shows up as "term" "org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.FieldLookup@1209016"

Comment: Sorry, I meant _field.logsource.value  See http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/modules/scripting.html

Comment: Turns out that I had to re-index it with the "index":"not_analyzed" field.  That did the trick.  Thanks!

Comment: Ivan, great info, maybe adding short info about "multifielding" the field would be a nice overview for the solution of the "my facets are broken how do I fix that" problem?

Comment: Great idea, Klement ;) I have added a multifield example to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I also got this same issue today while term aggregating in the recent elastic-search. After googling and some partial understanding, found how this geeky indexing works(which is very simple).

**Queries can find only terms that actually exist in the inverted index**

When you index the following string

```
"WEB-MISC /etc/passwd"
```

it will be passed to an analyzer. The analyzer might tokenize it into

```
"WEB", "MISC", "etc" and "passwd"
```

with its position details. And this tokens might filtered to lowercase such as

```
"web", "misc", "etc" and "passwd"
```

So, after indexing,the search query can see the above 4 only. not the complete word "WEB-MISC /etc/passwd". For your requirement the following are my options you can use

```
1.Change the Default Analyzer used by elasticsearch([link][1])
2.If it is not need, just TurnOff the analyzer by setting 'not_analyzed' for the fields you need
3.To convert the already indexed data searchable, re-indexing is the only option
```

Answer (score -1):

I have briefly explained this problem and proposed two solutions [here](https://qbox.io/blog/elasticsearch-aggregation-custom-analyzer).
I have talked about multiple approaches here.
One is use of not_analyzed to preserve the string as it is. But then as it has the drawback of being case insensitive , a better approach would be use keyword tokenizer + lowercase filter

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I have briefed my answer.